# How to pass a higher order function that takes variadic arguments in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to implement a function that composes the functions `g` and `f`, i.e. `g.f`. Ideally, I'd like f to take in a variadic number of arguments, so that the following code is valid:

```
def add (x: Int, y: Int) : Int = x + y
def addOne (x: Int) : Int = x + 1
def sq (x : Int) : Int = x * x

def compose[A, B, C] (g : B => C, f: A => B, args : A) : C = g(f(args))
assert(compose(sq, addOne, 5) == 36)

// this doesn't work yet
def compose_ideal[A, B, C] (g : B => C, f: (A*) => B, args : A*) : C = g(f(args))
assert(compose_ideal(sq, addOne, 5) == 36)
assert(compose_ideal(sq, add, 3, 7) == 100)
```

I get the following error for `compose_ideal`:

```
error: repeated parameters are only allowed in method signatures; use Seq instead
    def compose_ideal[A, B, C] (g : B => C, f: (A*) => B, args : A*) : C = g(f(args))
```

What I want to say in the function signature is that f is a function that takes a variadic number of arguments of type A, as expressed in `args: A*`. However, something like `def compose_ideal[A, B, C] (g : B => C, f: Seq[A] => B, args : A*) : C = g(f(args : _*))` doesn't work either because of type mismatch.

How do I solve this error?

Comment: **varargs** are not a type, they are just sugar syntax for **Seq**, use this: `def compose_ideal[A, B, C] (g : B => C, f: Seq[A] => B, args : A*) : C = g(f(args))` - BTWQ, your compose function is really hard to call since the functions go first and the data latter which makes type inference weaker and is just longer that just writing `g(f(a))` by hand.

Comment: Does that actually work? Your solution still gives me a type mismatch when I do something like `assert(compose_ideal(sq, addOne, 5) == 36)` saying it expects a Seq instead of (Int, Int). Also, this is just an exercise to understand function composition I think, not actually something practical I guess?

Comment: You can not pass `addOne` there, because it expects a function that takes a sequence of values and `addOne` does not accept a sequence. - And because it is an exercise is that I am telling you the bad things about that. A better one would be `def compose[A, B, C](a: A)(f: A => B)(g: B => C): C = g(f(a))` And just forget about **varargs**, they are not really that useful, they just serve as a minor API improvement, the fact that they use **Seq** already make them very bad; and in this case is not really worth it.

Comment: `compose_ideal()` doesn't work but `compose()` actually does, sort of: `assert(compose(sq, (add _).tupled, (3,7)) == 100)`